# What attribute should be checked for a registered variable under two Ansible when conditions

Tags: ansible, attributes, runtimeexception, .when

How do we check for a registered variable if only one of the two conditions turns out to be true having the same registered variable?

Below is my playbook that executes only one of the two shell modules.

```
- name: Check file
    shell: cat /tmp/front.txt
    register: myresult
  when: Layer == 'front'

- name: Check file
    shell: cat /tmp/back.txt
    register: myresult
  when: Layer == 'back'

- debug:
    msg: data was read from back.txt and print whatever
  when: Layer == 'back' and myresult.rc != 0

- debug:
    msg: data was read from front.txt and print whatever
  when: Layer == 'front' and myresult.rc != 0
```

Run the above playbook as

`ansible-playbook test.yml -e Layer="front"`

I do get error that says myresult does not have an attribute `rc`. What is the best way to print debug one statements based on the condition met?

I tried `myresult is changed` but that too does not help. Can you please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ignore_errors: true` and change the task order. Try as below.

```
  - name: Check file
    shell: cat /tmp/front.txt
    register: myresult
    when: Layer == 'front'
  - debug:
     msg: data was read from front.txt and print whatever
    when: not myresult.rc
    ignore_errors: true


  - name: Check file
    shell: cat /tmp/back.txt
    register: myresult
    when: Layer == 'back'
  - debug:
     msg: data was read from back.txt and print whatever
    when: not myresult.rc
    ignore_errors: true
```

Comment: instead of `debug:` if I have the `fail:` module which should fail if condition met, then how will we address this issue? `ignore_errors` will not help I guess. Any clues?

Comment: Not sure exactly what your requirement is. But from what i understood, try using failed_when instead of when,as below   - debug:
     msg: data was read from front.txt and print whatever
    failed_when: not myresult.rc